# THREE.js Update rotation property of object after rotateOnWorldAxis

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use `rotateOnWorldAxis` to rotate my mesh object. Before I apply the rotations, the mesh has its rotation data as Euler object with rotation value for each axis.

in `mesh.rotation`:

```
// Euler (_x: 1.5707963267948961 _y: 1.3439035240356314 _z: 3.141592653589793)
```

I have some angles that I would like my mesh to rotate on each axis, so I am doing the following:

```
// define axis vectors and angles
const xAngle = some angle in Radians
const xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
...same for Y and Z axis

// apply rotateOnWorldAxis
mesh.rotateOnWorldAxis(xAxis, xAngle);
...same for Y and Z axis
```

After using `rotateOnWorldAxis` method on my mesh object, I can visually see that my mesh has rotated correctly. However, when I inspect the object after applying the rotations, the `mesh.rotation` property does not change and still contains values from before the rotations.

In fact, all of its properties regarding transformation (e.g., `matrix`, `matrixWorld`, `position`, `quaternion`) remain unchanged, while the rendered mesh does rotate visually.

How do I trigger my mesh object to update all of its transformation data after applying `rotateOnWorldAxis`?

Comment: Hi, do you have a complete example? I can't reproduce this problem.